# PHP use variable to pass multiple arguments to function

Tags: php, function, variables, arguments, parameter-passing

I have a function that expects 9 arguments to be passed to it.  The first argument it expects is a string, the rest are ints.

Here is the function:

```
 getProductPrice('red', 8, 1.6, 2.15, 0, 0, 0, 17.6, 0);
```

When that gets run, it works fine.  However, when I run it like this:

```
 getProductPrice("'red'".','.$arguments);
```

It does not work.

```
"'red'".','.$arguments
```

outputs:  'red', 8, 1.6, 2.15, 0, 0, 0, 17.6, 0

If anyone could tell me how to use the $arguments variable in place of all the arguments?

What I ended up suspecting was making it not work, is that what $arguments is outputting is a string, so I looked into how to convert a comma separated string of numbers into a php function's arguments.

I came across this:

```
$params = explode(',', $str);
call_user_func_array("func", $params);
```

I can't figure out how to use this solution for two reasons:
1.  I need to pass a string along with the numbers.
2.  simply putting my function name where it says "func" in that example won't work, because it's a cakephp function, which requires me to put $this->ModelName->functionname, which breaks the first argument in the call_user_func_array function()

Any ideas how to help me guys?

I could just put the variables that make $arguments output what it does, but it's a ton of complicated logic and math to get each of those numbers, so my function calls would look ridiculous.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try replacing the `"func"` string with `array($this->ModelName, 'functionname')`. The first element in this array is the object on which you call the method, the second is a string representation of the name of this method. This way it should work:

```
$params = explode(',', $str);
call_user_func_array(array($this->ModelName, 'functionname'), $params);
```

Of course replace the placeholder names with your own.

Comment: This got me there.  Thanks!  I will accept the answer as soon as it allows me to.  I also had to change the 1st argument to an int like the rest of them and then convert the int to the proper string based on the int within the function itself.